# Use bash script to read numbers

Tags: linux, bash

Write a bash script that will read 10 integers from users and append the output to a file ‘XYZ’.  You are not allowed to use the ‘read’ statement more than once in the script.

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
do
    read "i"
    echo "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" >> XYZ
done
```

I am a student just bengin to learn this, I feel it is difficult, could you give me some suggestions? I think this should have many problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you can try to read the whole line with integers using -a option (see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)). Of course then the user must input all of the integers at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what you already have. Your `for` loop does 10 iterations of a `read` command, and `read` appears only once in the script. You also append (`>>`) your output to the file `XYZ`.

You shouldn't use the same variable for loop counter and reading the input, though. And the sequence could be shortened to `{0..9}`.

What you're still missing is a condition to check that the user input actually is an integer. And you're probably supposed to output the value you read, not the string `"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"`.

---

On a more general note, you may find the following guides helpful with learning `bash`:

- [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)
- [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: I know that those two guides are well-known and often cited, but a *much* better introduction to Bash is this one: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Input 10 integers separated by commas:'
read line
nums=`echo -n "$line" | sed "s/,/ /g"`
for i in $nums; do
    echo "$i" >> XYZ
done
```

If you input `9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0`, those numbers will be appended to the `XYZ` file, each one in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Read 10 (or less,or more) integers into an array, output not more than the first 10:

```
read -p '10 integers please: ' -a number 
IFS=,
echo  "${number[*]:0:10}" >> XYZ
```

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Output, comma separated:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
```